# Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/module.so'

Tags: php, php-extension

When I run the command

```
php -v
```

this error comes up

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/module.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2013 02:37:06)

Comment: Have you checked if the file is actually there?

Comment: Yes I did, there was no such file.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is cause by mcrypt extension.

Edit /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini

and change

```
; Enable mcrypt extension module
extension=module.so
```

to this

```
; Enable mcrypt extension module
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Edit:

> mini

If the directory /etc/php.d does not exist – it seems You don`t have php installed or file mcrypt.ini is in different location. Try work around.

Comment: in addition, mcrypt.so is also added into php.ini and you need to comment it out from there and only leave it active in `/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini`

Comment: The directory `/etc/php.d` does not exist!