# Yii2 - PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php-5.5.21/lib/php/20121212/zip.so'

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Anyone can help me to solve my problem, when i migrate my script to share hosting and the hosting use php version 5.5.21 i got this error meesage on all pages :

PHP Core Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php-5.5.21/lib/php/20121212/zip.so' - /usr/local/php-5.5.21/lib/php/20121212/zip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

i tried to search in google but i didnt find the answer, on php.ini i already set

; Enable zip extension module
extension = zip.so

i contacted the hosting no solution too, maybe someone have a solution for me,

thanks

Comment: i guess this [similarlink1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16677559/3623027) or this [similar2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25800203/3623027) will help..

Comment: Thanks for your reply... by default my hosting setting php.ini by enable extension = zip.so, ... when i tried disable .. the problem SOLVED

Answer (score 2):

My version php is 7.0 but it must work 5.x version too.

If you have file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/zip.ini

```
extension=zip.so
```

comment extension=zip.so line in php.ini

after that restart php it must work.

Answer (score 1):

i faced a similar problem with newrelic.so its happened because some codes try to call a missed library or extensions so all you need to check your extensions by

```
grep -Hrv ";" /etc/php5 | grep -i "extension="
```

in my case i didn't find the newrelic.so so i just install it

```
sudo apt-get install newrelic-php5
```

thin i restart the Apache service by

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

for your problem i think you are missing zip.so extensions so all you need to install it by

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip
```

thin restart  apache2 
i hope this helpful for you

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem with yii when I'm using php 7.4 but not 7.3 for lib intl.so
what I did is that to comment lib intl.so on php.ini
perhaps you can do the same thing for zip.zo ?

Comment: please use comment instead as more relevant answer already posted.